# How do I get the text of a button with Toast

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-toast

I have a bunch of buttons with( the texts inside are date like FRI 12 ) in the screen for user to select. I want to get the text from the selected button to pass it to another activity but still struggle.

I google it for hours and try the code like this

```
private String date_selected;

public void onClick(View button) {

    Button b = (Button)button;
    date_selected = b.getText().toString();
    Log.d("myTag", date_selected);
    Toast.makeText(this,date_selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me to solve the problem, I have 3 hours left for my deadline (this is a small homework for my mobile course).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you want to get text of the clicked button ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Are you getting any error? What does the logcat show?

Comment: I can build and run the app but the logcat didn't show anything ... 
@VivekMishra yes I want to get the text of the selected button

Comment: The above code should crash saying **The log needs a message to print** .. but the log is null

Comment: @TrungLe Have you attached on click listener to the button? Otherwise, this method won't be called.

Comment: @Froyo this method seems like defined in xml using `onClick` attribute

Comment: b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                date_selected = b.getText().toString();
    Log.d("myTag", date_selected);
  Toast.makeText(this, dateSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//if not display try Toast.makeText(ACTIVITY_NAME.this, dateSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me,my code works ok but I missed the .show() method of the toast so it did not show up. For the onClick I have defined in the xml :). 

Thank you all, I am very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show your Toast by adding `.show()` at the end:

```
Toast.makeText(this, dateSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, what a silly mistake I made, so the code in my post works well, but because I missed the .show method of Toast so it didn't show up in the screen

Answer (score 2):

If you're not having `android:onClick` attribute in your XML, make sure you have following in your code :

```
buttonXYZ.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Else double check your `android:onClick` method name

Also, as suggested by others, call `.show()` after your toast

Comment: he is defining onClick in layout file so this is not required

Comment: actually, he didn't mention that

Comment: you can see that there is no override annotation for his click method

Comment: that's right, but he might have not included the annotation in the question. Anyway, have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your

```
 Toast.makeText(this,date_selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

with

```
 Toast.makeText(this,date_selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

, otherwise the Toast is created but never shown.